# for loop "Invalid expression term '<'"

Tags: c#

It shows me error under the `<` symbol

> Invalid expression term '<'

```
    {
        int[] myarray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        for (int i = 0, i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            if (myarray[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add ( myarray[i].ToString() );
            }
            else
            {
                listView2.Items.Add ( myarray[i].ToString() );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably meant to use ";" there.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is the `for`

You will notice the following errors

> - CS1525  Invalid expression term '<'
> - CS0128  A local variable or function named 'i' is already defined in this scope
> - CS1002  ; expected

The last one is probably the most accurate for your actual problem, its saying you are missing a `;`. however when you think about it, all the errors are telling you exactly what you need to know and what it thinks is wrong

What you had

```
for (int i = 0, i < 10 ; i++)
```

What you should have

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) // notice the ;
```

[for (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)

> **Structure of the for statement**
>
> The for statement defines `initializer`, `condition`, and `iterator`
>   sections:
>
> ```
> for (initializer; condition; iterator)
>     body
> ```

---

Great comment from [Flydog57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4739488/flydog57)

> It's worth noting that having a comma before the first semicolon is
>   valid in a for statement, but, a comparison expression (i.e., the `<`)
>   isn't. Hence the error. For example, assuming `j` was previously
>   declared, this is valid:
>
> ```
> for(var i=0, j=0; i<10; ++i, j+=5).
> ```
>
> The statement initializes `i` and `j` at the start of the loop, checks `i` as a
>   loop condition, and the increments both variables (by different
>   amounts) at the end of the loop.

Comment: oh my god - - I see, the error message should be more understandable for beginner.

Comment: @LightLuke unfortunately this is such a simple mistake and there are several more complex usages of a for that it would be unpractical to suggest you missed a `;` when it could be so many other things

Comment: @LightLuke: It's worth noting that having a comma before the first semicolon is valid in a `for` statement, but, a comparison expression (i.e., the `<`) isn't. Hence the error. For example, assuming `j` was previously declared, this is valid: `for(var i=0, j=0; i<10; ++i, j+=5)`. The statement initializes `i` and `j` at the start of the loop, checks `i` as a loop condition, and the increments both variables (by different amounts) at the end of the loop.